# Click on element stored in javascript object not working

Tags: javascript, click

I'm trying to select an DOM element and store it in an object and then later accessing it by a click event.

```
this._elements.convertButton.click(function(e) {
    _this.convertButtonClicked.notify();
});
```

If I initially select the element using JQuery all is fine

```
{ convertButton: $("#convert") }
```

However if I don't use JQuery the click does not work

```
{ convertButton: document.getElementById("convert") }
```

While using Jquery is not an major issue I was simply looking for clarification on how to make it work using pure javascript and why the click is fine on the JQuery object and not on the ordinary object.

Comment: The [*click* method](http://api.jquery.com/click/) of a jQuery object (the return from `$('convert')`) is quite different from the [*click* method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/click) of a DOM object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two solutions:

**1.** jQuery:

```
$(this._elements.convertButton).click(function(e) {
    _this.convertButtonClicked.notify();
});
```

**2.** Plain Javascript:

```
this._elements.convertButton.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    _this.convertButtonClicked.notify();
}
```

**Explanation:**
What's probably happening is this._elements.convertButton is an Element instance, not a jQuery object, so the jQuery `.click()` method is unavailable. You can either use the standard `.addEventListener('click', ...` as an alternative, or wrap `this._elements.convertButton` in a jQuery object by using `$(this._elements.convertButton)`.

Answer (score 2):

Need to use [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener):

```
this._elements.convertButton.addEventListener("click",function(e) {
    _this.convertButtonClicked.notify();
});
```